# Azure Function in C# on v2 - How to access the portal Application Settings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

As of September 2019 coding an Azure Function in C# has some crossover with ASP.NET Core, especially around dependency injection.

Does the hidden "host builder" read the runtime Application Settings - which I think are actually just environment variables at runtime - into the configuration system, `IConfiguration`?

Thus, double underscore names can be used to recreate the hierarchical config we C# devs know.

Comment: If you want to know how to read app settings，please refer to https://www.koskila.net/how-to-access-azure-function-apps-settings-from-c/

Comment: You want to read app settings or add settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions support a similar convention as ASP.NET Core.

```
"EmailSettings__Sender": "xy@gmail.com",
"EmailSettings__From": "Hello xy@gmail.com",
```

Can be bound to the following POCO

```cs
 public class EmailSettings
 {
       public string Sender { get; set; }
       public string From { get; set; }
 }
```

using the `ConfigurationBuilder` like this:

```
 var provider = builder.Services
                .BuildServiceProvider();

 var executionContextOptions = provider
                              .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>()
                              .Value;

   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(executionContextOptions.AppDirectory)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                .Build();

 // other initialization code
config.GetSection(nameof(EmailSettings)).Get<EmailSettings>()
```

in the startup of your function. For deployment, put those key / value pairs into the App Settings of your function in the portal.

Thats how we set it up in production and it works fine.

Comment: If you have a reference link to some documentation that supports this it would be helpful to also include it in your answer.

Comment: @Nkosi : Up to date and comprehensive documentation about Azure Functions is hard to come by, especially some "edge-cases" like configuration. There is no official document from Microsoft regarding Azure Functions and complex app settings but them and ASP.NET Core have some common ground.

Comment: I was just saying if you have one. It was not a demand. Was just hoping you had better luck in find documentation than I did when searching. (yes I know you were kidding. No offense taken)

Comment: @Nkosi I hear you, I was spending quite some time as well and had to put the pieces of the puzzle together.